# CE certification

Tags: emc, manufacturing, test, test-equipment, production-testing

One of the required CE test technical files is "Test Reports". This document has to be provided to the test agency.

Does anyone know what data should be included in this document?

**Here are the required files including test reports**:
EC Declaration of Conformity

Information about the manufacturer

Product information and technical information

Operation and maintenance manual

Electrical drawings

Technical drawings

Product information and warning labels

List of applied regulations and standards

Test reports

Product specific risk analysis list

Appropriate documentation and certifications for components

Technical File preparation and storage procedure

Comment: The only documents you provide to the test agency are what they ask you for in order to book their time. Do you really mean this?

Comment: also, gut feeling: If an agency you pay asks you for documents... ask them?

Comment: The required files details are added to the question

Comment: The actual data depends on just what the product is.

Comment: Last time I saw some CE certification done forms were passed around without any testing because the engineers were sure it would be fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the nature of your product that you intend to CE-Mark.  Here are some brief examples where testing is required:
1.  Your product includes electronics that could generate RF.  You would have to undergo EMC testing to assure that your product does not exceed maximum allowable emissions.  You would include the test lab's report in your technical dossier.
2.  You are building an enclosure in which you intend to house electronics for use in Ex Zone 2.  You must test the enclosure to demonstrate that it meets the required IP rating.  The results would be in your test report.

If your product cannot be shown to comply with applicable EU directives by  calculations, tables, or exemptions, then you must perform tests to prove compliance.

By the way, CE is not a certification.  It's a declaration of conformity, declaring that the product complies with all EU directives applicable to the product.  With the CE-Mark, a product can be sold throughout the EU and be transported across borders within the EU.  The certification is different.  A product usually has to meet multiple certifications.  Many of these may be self certified.  The ones that address the most hazardous conditions must be performed by a Notified Body, such as TUV, BV, DNV, etc.

When you get your technical dossier together, it must be lodged (stored) within the EU member states.  Often a Notified Body will offer this service for a small fee.  If the Notified Body lodging the dossier had no hand in assembling these documents, they will treat what you give them simply as an envelope or CD, without regard to the validity of the content.

A final word about CE-Mark.  If you put it on a product but the product knowingly doesn't comply, you could be exposed to criminal charges in the EU.

I touched on just a few high points; there's far more to this.  I encourage you to work with a Notified Body if this is your first time through this process!